# Reuse static table view (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitableview

In my app I am using an `UITableViewController` for entering data. Now I want to use the same table in another view controller for modifying the data.

My idea: Implement an additional view controller and let these two inherit from it. All controls are the same and most of the behavior as well. However, in both I need some additional properties, in the one a delegate, and 1-2 methods must be overridden. So far so gut.

My problem: I cannot have static table (with sections and rows) in .xib file. So I cannot really reuse my table.

My question: How do I use such inherited controllers in storyboards? I need one for the common superclass. However, I cannot use it directly, it doesn't have all properties and methods that I need. And I really don't want to try doing everything in one class. So what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already checked out the free Sensible TableView framework? Seems to provide what you need out of box.

Comment: Hi, I think this framework should be able to solve my problem. However, I already put everything in the same class, together with a property for the distinctions that I need. Well, it's not that bad right now, hope I won't need other functionalities. And if so, I will consider using the Sensible TableView framework. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can just make the table view controller in the storyboard, and use

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil]; 
ExampleView *eg = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ExampleView"];
```

and keep it as a singleton and just segue to it when you need it. then you will be able to use it multiple times without it being destroyed

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem. I need two different table view controllers using the same table. I know that I can use a single one and make it pretty complex but I want to avoid this. And I want to avoid the alternative of splitting my table into 10 files and reusing them as well.

Answer (score 0):

In a storyboard, you can always load a view using `-[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`. It returns a new instance of the view controller, so it works just like loading a NIB.

---

```
id vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Static Table"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve my problem. I need two different table view controllers using the same table. I know that I can use a single one and make it pretty complex but I want to avoid this. And I want to avoid the alternative of splitting my table into 10 files and reusing them as well.